# Git not opening in the defaullt text editor as configured in the /.gitconfig file

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, terminal, nano

When i type the git command to open the default text editor ,git should open VScode but it actually opens nano.

git config --global -e

> ```
>          GNU nano 5.7               /home/xyz/.gitconfig
> > # This is Git's per-user configuration file. [user]
> >         name =xyx
> >         email = xyz@gmail.com [code]
> >         editor = code --w [core]
> >         autocrlf = input
> ```

any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `git config --global -e` does not invoke the git configured editor, but the system editor.

To edit the git config inside git you have to issue the following commands:

```sh
export EDITOR=code
git config --global -e
```

If it is right for you I suggest to you to set `EDITOR` variable inside your `RC` file.

Comment: Thanks it works now and by RC file you mean /.gitconfig  file ,right ?

Comment: I mean  `$HOME/.bash_rc` or `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: `git config --global --edit` *does* invoke the `core.editor` if it is set and not overridden by some other higher priority setting (I tested this in Git 2.27.0 but it should be true in all versions). But setting `EDITOR` or `GIT_EDITOR` is a good way to get around a chicken-and-egg problem if you want to use a specific editor before setting `core.editor` or if `core.editor` is mis-set.

Comment: Thanks ,
and i found out that we need to add export EDITOR='code --w' in place of export EDITOR=code  for git commit  .

Comment: I just do `<your-favorite-editor> ~/.gitconfig`. ;-)